# Python 3.5: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, list, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have this piece of Python code:

```
homedir = '/home/cloudera/'
baseurl = 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/'

apilist = ['seasons', 'results', 'qualifying', 'driverStandings', 'constructorStandings', 'drivers', 'constructors',
           'circuits', 'status', 'laps', 'pitstops']

for dir in apilist:
    target = homedir + str(dir)
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(target, ignore_errors=True)
        os.makedirs(target)
    except:
        pass

parent_url = baseurl + "{y}/{api}.json?limit=100000"
parent_fname = homedir + "{api}/{yf}.json"


urls = [parent_url.format(y=y, api=a) for y, a in itertools.product(range(1950, 2016), apilist)]
files = [parent_fname.format(yf=y, api=a) for y, a in itertools.product(range(1950, 2016), apilist)]


for url, file in zip(urls, files):
    print(url, file)
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
       json.dump(response, f)
```

When I run this, this is the output I get:

```
/home/cloudera/PycharmProjects/ErgastF1/ErgastF1/bin/python /home/cloudera/PycharmProjects/ErgastF1/F1Demo.py
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/seasons.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/seasons/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/results.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/results/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/qualifying.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/qualifying/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/driverStandings.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/driverStandings/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/constructorStandings.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/constructorStandings/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/drivers.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/drivers/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/constructors.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/constructors/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/circuits.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/circuits/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/status.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/status/1950.json
http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/laps.json?limit=100000 /home/cloudera/laps/1950.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/PycharmProjects/ErgastF1/F1Demo.py", line 74, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url).json()
  File "/home/cloudera/PycharmProjects/ErgastF1/ErgastF1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 812, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Basically, it creates the JSON files for the year 1950, but the next time the loop runs for the year 1951, it exits. I'm new to Python and newer still to JSON. Can someone figure out what's going on?

Note: A less complex version of this program, with all the years from 1950 to 2015, but only with `qualifying` had worked. I was trying to go large scale and get all attributes together. That version merely used a range to iterate through the years and generate file names and urls.

Comment: Can you insert the json file on question? This error appears to be a corrupted or invalid file

Comment: The files that do get generated are valid. The moment it gets to 1951, it exits with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem are raised because the url: http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/laps.json?limit=100000 returns a error. Look the url:http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/status.json?limit=100000 (Image Above)[image]
This Image have a working json format, and the source this page is:
[image]

The url:http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/laps.json?limit=100000 return a html error:[image]

And the source of this url is a html table and not is a json format:[image]

This error can be suppresed using a error treatment, but cant resolve the format. Maybe need some other argument in the url to return the corret values.
I this link: http://ergast.com/mrd/ have the documentation of this api, and in the section *Overview* says:

[image]

If you try to put a numeric value into a url after year, like : http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/1/laps.json?limit=100000 you return some valid results, like this image:[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I should've read the documents more carefully. Upon further testing, even `pitstops` were subject to the same constraint. I removed `laps` and `pitstops` and it worked fine. Thank you! :)